# What is the zero value for an Enum?

Tags: solidity

What is the zero value of an Emum when initialized inside a struct of a mapping ?

Comment: Hi there. Does this previous answer help? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/how-are-enums-converted-to-uint

Answer (score 11):

The default value of the enum variable/field is first value of an enum which has index 0.

Comment: Thanks! is there a citation/documentation around evm encoding of enums?